# What's grammar of "the reasonable satisfaction of both parties " in the text?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> Express terms are set out and stipulated expressly in the contract.
> For example: The Seller will within a period of 6 months from the date
> of delivery of Goods, where Goods which are proved to **the reasonable
> satisfaction of both parties** to be damaged or defective or not to
> comply with the agreed specification due to defects in materials or
> workmanship or to faulty design, repair, or at its sole discretion
> replace, such Goods, subject to the following.

The above text is in Cambridge Business English, I can understand the meaning of the text, but I cannot tell the grammar fact of the bold part in the text. Some people told me that it is the indirect object of 'proved to', Is that right?

Comment: I tried to find the usage of 'prove' online, but it seems that 'prove' is not used in the passive tense.

Comment: No: there is no indirect object. The expression "the reasonable satisfaction of both parties" is complement of the preposition "to" and the PP "to the reasonable satisfaction of both parties" then functions as complement of "proved".

Comment: Would it be possible that the pp "to the reasonable satisfaction of both parties" functions as the adverbial of 'proved‘?  @BillJ

Comment: No: adverbials express such meanings as manner, spatial or temporal location, duration, condition and so om, It's a complement licensed by "proved".